# MOOC Helsinki Java/ Part 4/ Exercise 1(Your First Account)

Tags: java

I'm doing MOOC Helsinki course for Java and until part 4 of Java I, everything was all right. "Account" Class is already written by MOOC, I just need to create Account Class Object in YourFirstAccount class, deposit 20 to it and print final balance, It shows correctly to console, but when I try to submit, gives back this error:

> Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @44198d29 java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doGetAllMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1499) org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getAllMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1473) org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findMethodOrThrowException(WhiteboxImpl.java:853) org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:813) org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:681) org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401) org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.getResult(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:76) org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.invokeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:64) org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.executeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:56) org.powermock.classloading.SingleClassloaderExecutor.execute(SingleClassloaderExecutor.java:33) org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.execute(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:40) org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:75) org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271) org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70) org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50) org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) fi.helsinki.cs.tmc.testrunner.TestRunner$TestingRunnable.runTestCase(TestRunner.java:134) fi.helsinki.cs.tmc.testrunner.TestRunner$TestingRunnable.doRun(TestRunner.java:89) fi.helsinki.cs.tmc.testrunner.TestRunner$TestingRunnable.run(TestRunner.java:70) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

My Code:

```
public class YourFirstAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Do not touch the code in Account.java
        // Write your program here
        Account myAccount = new Account("My Account", 100.00);
        
        myAccount.deposit(20.00);
        
        System.out.println(myAccount);
    }

}

Code that was already written my MOOC:
/\*

* DO NOT TOUCH THIS !
  \*/

public class Account {

    private double balance;
    private String owner;
    
    public Account(String owner, double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    
    public void deposit(double amount) {
        this.balance = this.balance + amount;
    }
    
    public void withdrawal(double amount) {
        this.balance = this.balance - amount;
    }
    
    public double saldo() {
        return this.balance;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.owner + " balance: " + this.balance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar error when I submitted to "TMC", but when I sent the same solution to the server, it worked.

```java
public class YourFirstAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Do not touch the code in Account.java
        // Write your program here
        Account bobsAccount = new Account("Bob's account", 100.0);
        bobsAccount.deposit(20.0);
        System.out.println(bobsAccount);
    }
}
```